# One word for brief interactions with strangers

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for a brief interaction with a stranger, for example, when someone offers you their seat on the bus or holds the elevator for you?

Edit: The interaction needn't necessarily be polite or courteous. It might even just be somebody tripping over their own two feet and bumping up against you at the bar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**encounter** (*noun*):

an unexpected or casual meeting with someone or something

> '*When you go to work, or visit a park, it is possible that you will have a range of unexpected encounters, however fleeting or seemingly inconsequential.*'

Other suggestions include:

**meeting** (*noun*):

(Defn. 2) a situation when two or people meet, by chance or arrangement

> '*While there, I've met people I already knew by chance and had chance meetings with new people.*'

You would probably need to refer to '**chance meetings**', or '**meeting by chance'**.

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: +1 Hi Julie, thanks for the answer. This really seems like the perfect word, but I can't use it because here in India, it usually connotes police killings. Yes, really. Here's a link to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encounter_killings_by_police). Would you perhaps be able to suggest another word?

Comment: @Tragicomic my goodness, thanks for pointing that out to me. I will have another think for you:)

Comment: Encounter implies running up against something that presents a hardship, difficulty, or obstacle. There has, however, been a progressive weakening of this sense.

Comment: @Mysti Often such brief encounters with strangers cause interruptions in our thoughts or actions. In this way, you might say an encounter is still "running up against... an obstacle".

Comment: I think _encounter_ is reasonable. Encounters do not need to be at an extreme such as hardship, etc. The first word that came to my mind though was _exchange_, but I like _encounter_ better here because it's more stand-alone, where _exchange_ almost screams for more description.

Answer (score 2):

Another good word would be ["have a brush with"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+brush+with):

> have a brush with something
>
> to have a brief contact with something; to 
>   have an experience with something. (Especially with the law. Sometimes
>   a close brush.) Ann had a close brush with the law. She was nearly
>   arrested for speeding. When I was younger, I hada brush with scarlet
>   fever, but I got over it.

Comment: Also, *had a run in with*. But both of these are phrases and generally negative.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this answer. As you say, "have a brush with" means to have a brief contact with something, although not usually another person.

Answer (score 1):

When people say (informally) that they *run into each other* or *come together*, the event is strictly a **convergence**.

> Convergence (?), Convergency (?) , n. [Cf. F. convergence.]
>   1. The condition or quality of converging; tendency to one point; the occurrence of two or more things coming together.
>
> [1913 Webster]

To play up the seemingly predestined aspects of these interactions, you can use **happenstance**. You can also use **coincidence**.

From WordNet 3.0:

> n 1: an event that might have been arranged although it was really accidental [syn: {coincidence}, {happenstance}]

Comment: Also, thanks for the "encounter" information. Interesting stuff.

Comment: +1 I like "convergence" though it isn't exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. About "encounter," yes, it's interesting how words take on a life of their own travelling around the world.

Answer (score 0):

While not a single word, perhaps the phrase *fleeting acquaintance* might suit. *Collins* defines *[acquaintance](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/acquaintance)* as

> knowledge of a person or thing, esp when slight

As @JulieCarter suggests in her answer, *[fleeting](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/fleeting?showCookiePolicy=true)* is often used to refer to such meetings. *Collins* defines this as

> passing swiftly; not lasting

Answer (score 0):

you could use a descriptive word such as 'politeness' if you are talking about the action